# Plug HDMI VGA cables in to two Laptos

Tags: hdmi, vga

I have One Laptop(HDMI) and one PC (VGA) Monitor supports BOTH HDMI and VGA. so I usually keep my VGA connected to the PC,where asLaptop connected to the HDMI.
Since only one computer works at a time. is there any impact to the switched of PC/Laptop if I keep the cables conneted?  both are windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no impact of keeping both computers connected to the monitor since you are just switching sources on the monitor.